# php не вычитается 1.000.000 из $_GET числа

Tags: php, сервер, post, get

Спасибо за то, что хотите помочь мне. Есть проблема - задается число через параметр $_GET, Есть проверки на то, что это число и т.д., но при этом нельзя вычесть 1.000.000 из данного числа, отображает это же число, вот основные части кода:

(Параметр comid=1000006)

```
$id = $_GET["comid"]; 

....

$id -= 1000000;
echo $id;
```

Вывод:

```
1000006
```

Что делать?

Самое интересное, что проверку:

```
if($id < 1000000) {}
```

Он проходит верно

Comment: Попробуйте `$id = intval($_GET["comid"]);`

Comment: Иван, не помогло

Comment: @screaming-voices В этих строках $id только просматривается и подставляется в строки "".$id.""

Comment: @screaming-voices 7.0.19

Comment: @screaming-voices я скопировал. Если вам это чем-то поможет:``

Comment: $que4 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `discussion` WHERE `id` = '".($id-1000000)."'");
            $id -= 1000000;
            echo $id;
            $globalg;
            if(mysql_num_rows($que4) !== 0) {
                for($l=0; $l<mysql_num_rows($que4); $l++) {
                    $g = mysql_fetch_array($que4);
                    $globalg = $g;
                }
            }

Comment: Извиняюсь, в первом сообщении хотел код вставить

Comment: @screaming-voices Самое интересное, что проверку: `if($id < 1000000) {}` он проходит, попробовал ваш вариант, не помогло

Comment: @LoBemDev что выводит `var_dump($id);` до `$id-=`?

Comment: @screaming-voices Вы удивитесь, но ничего

Comment: `var_dump($_GET)` ?

Comment: @br3t `var_dump($_GET["comid"])`

Comment: Ну так выводится что-то там?

Comment: @br3t придется немного подождать, у меня хостинг полетел